# How To Code this formula in Php?

Tags: php, math, formula, equation-solving

I have tried to represent this formula in php but the values are not correct maybe I have some issue transforming the formula to code

```
p*|log(0.15*(m-2)|
```

Comment: Have you tried something...

Answer (score 0):

```
$value = p * abs(log(0.15 * (m - 2)));
```

Typecast any values to integer/float/double if they're strings.

Comment: `m` and `p` will throw undefined exception.

Comment: Yeah I don't know what m or p is, the assumption is that they're variables.